# Codeigniter not showing 404

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I want to show 404 page when someone writes a slash at the end of the URL

- `http://www.example.com/abc` (Correct URL)
- `http://www.example.com/abc/` (i want to show 404 error)

Comment: please explain why you think a trailing backslash would qualify for a 404?

Comment: cuz google think that it's a duplicate link and its added in black list  that's why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If none of your URLs end in a trailing slash and you don't need to access any filesystem directories directly then you can add the following at the *top* of your `.htaccess` file, *before* the existing Codeigniter directives, to serve a 404 instead:

```
# Trigger 404 for any URL that ends in a slash
RewriteRule /$ - [R=404]
```

---

Alternatively, you could remove the trailing slash instead. ie. redirect any URL that ends in a slash (that is not a filesystem directory) to the non-slash version of the URL. For example:

```
# Remove trailing slash (except for directories)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The above would redirect `/abc/` to `/abc`, thus avoiding the duplicate content issue.

NB: Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

You need to exclude directories otherwise mod_dir will try to reappend the trailing slash and you would get a redirect loop.

---

*Aside:* You need to make sure that you are consistently linking to the correct canonical URL, ie. without the trailing slash. If Google is indexing URLs with a trailing slash then it indicates it has found these URLs somewhere.